# The request matched multiple endpoints SMS API controller

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, exception, routes

I'm working on implementing the Nexmo API into my code and have run into some issues with the controller. I'm getting the error

AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
gardenplanning.Controllers.SMSController.Send (gardenplanning)
gardenplanning.Controllers.SMSController.Send (gardenplanning)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)

I have a feeling that it has to do with the 2 "Send" methods however I'm out of ideas as to how to modify one of them to fix the routing. The code integrated into my project is below. I commented out the Index method because in my HomeController it already has method that maps to Index. Any help as to what's causing the issue would be appreciated, thanks.

enter code here

```
namespace gardenplanning.Controllers {
    public class SMSController : Controller
    {
        /*
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        */

        //Send Action Method

        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Send()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Action method containing "to" and "text" params
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Send(string to, string text)
        {
            var results = SMS.Send(new SMS.SMSRequest
            {
                from = Configuration.Instance.Settings["appsettings:NEXMO_FROM_NUMBER"],
                to = to,
                text = text
            });
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The guide for Nexmo API is below

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Send()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Send(string to, string text)
        {

        var results = SMS.Send(new SMS.SMSRequest
            {

                from = Configuration.Instance.Settings["appsettings:NEXMO_FROM_NUMBER"],
                to = to,
                text = text
            });
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access? Are you trying to access from Browser? From Code?

Comment: Hi @Mike, any updates about this case?

Comment: Ah yes a friend was able to help me refactor some of the code. @FeiHan

Answer (score 0):

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: gardenplanning.Controllers.SMSController.Send (gardenplanning) gardenplanning.Controllers.SMSController.Send (gardenplanning) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)

As exception message indicated, the request matched two or more endpoints, which cause the issue.

To [resolve ambiguous actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#resolving-ambiguous-actions) you can try to apply different [HTTP verb templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#http-verb-templates) to these two "Send" action methods, which constrains matching to requests with specific HTTP method only. And in ASP.NET Core app, you can use `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]` instead of `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]`.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Send()
{
    return View();
}

//Action method containing "to" and "text" params
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(string to, string text)
{
    var results = SMS.Send(new SMS.SMSRequest
    {
        from = Configuration.Instance.Settings["appsettings:NEXMO_FROM_NUMBER"],
        to = to,
        text = text
    });
    return View();
}
```

Besides, if you'd like to conditionally enable or disable an action for a given request based on query string, you can try to implement a custom [ActionMethodSelectorAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.actionmethodselectorattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1). For more information, please check this blog:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/defining-asp-net-core-controller-action-constraint-to-match-the-correct-action/